# Making a Heuristic Evaluation

Tags: usability, usability-testing, heuristics

I'm upgrading our IT (acted as Dev) and am delving more into UI and UX.

I've been reading the 10 heuristics of Nielsen and had a doubt: Is the analysis done as list check (ie, caught the first heuristic and sail throughout the project) or as something intrinsic, like, have it internally in my mind the watch the project completely observing all heuristics?

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to Conduct a Heuristic Evaluation](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/how-to-conduct-a-heuristic-evaluation/) from Jakob Nielsen, the same author of the 10 heuristics you have already read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do HEs by evaluating each heuristic on every step of the process. I make notes on each one, discussing how this step meets and fails to meet each heuristic. The notes then are put into a report, which sometimes includes screenshots for the client.

Of course, you'll eventually internalize many of the heuristics so they'll be in mind even when you're not explicitly performing an HE.

Also, after becoming an expert, you can modify the heuristic list for your particular business or client.